# How to Enable/Disable data grid column cell based on a list of values?

Tags: wpf, isenabled, datagridcolumn

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount($)" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path = Amount}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Tran_Code}" Value=**"DEP"**>
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>                                 
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Instead of just one values (as of now its DEP),the cell should be enabled for certain set of values

Comment: <DataGridTextColumn Header="Disbursements ($)" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path = Disbursements}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Tran_Code}" Value="DEP">
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                  
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>

Comment: What's the expected result? What doesn't work? Please use the "edit" button to rephrase your own question and put code there.

Comment: @Felis-I had posted my code but it was not refelcting.Later on i realised that theres format of posting codes out here.Before marking it down,you should ask the reason for it!

Comment: I DID NOT down-vote your question at all. Please don't blame me for the down-vote just because I've suggested improvements in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a converter:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount($)" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path = Amount}" Visibility="Binding Path = Tran_Code, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}"></DataGridTextColumn>

public class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string transcode = value.ToString();
                if (transcode == 1)
                    return Visibility.Hidden;                
                else
                    return Visibility.Visible;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this.mydatagrid.Columns[2].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

you can add the index of the column to be hidden.